# Can a single call of `rnorm` in R base generate two or more types of random variables?

Tags: r, random

## Question

I was wondering if a single call of `rnorm` in R base can generate two or more sets of random variables each with different `n`, different `mean`, and different `sd`?

## Details

As an example, in the below `rnorm` call, I'm trying to get `rnorm` to generate two sets of random variables, each with different `n`, different `mean`, and different `sd`:

```
rnorm( n = c(5, 3) , mean = c(6, 4) , sd = c(2, 1) )
```

Since the above attempt doesn't produce the desired result, I tried to `Vectorize` all the 3 arguments in the `rnorm`:

```
rnorm.2 = Vectorize( rnorm(n , mean, sd), "n", "mean", "sd")
```

And I encounter: `Error in rnorm(n, mean, sd) : invalid arguments`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for `mapply`:

```
> mapply(FUN = rnorm,n = c(4,5),mean = c(1,2),sd = c(10,11))
[[1]]
[1] -7.959507  4.778437  1.869498 10.247306

[[2]]
[1] 11.365440 10.609155 15.795004 -2.130115  9.389735
```